# "ist (passiv) erreichbar" zu "Erreichbarkeit" wie "kann (aktiv) erreichen" zu "???"

Tags: noun

Ich suche ein Wort *xyz* (ein Nomen), das sich zu *erreichend* (im Sinne von *A erreicht (aktiv) B* und im Sinne von *A kann einen Weg hin zu B zurücklegen*) verhält wie *Erreichbarkeit* zu *erreichbar*. So etwas wie *Erreichendheit* oder *-keit*, nur dass sich die beiden sehr falsch anhören.

Comment: Und was soll dieses Wort beschreiben? Der Zustand das etwas gerade erreicht wird?

Comment: Den Zustand, dass A (aktiv) B erreichen kann. Während B von A aus (passiv) erreichbar ist.

Comment: "erreichtend" ist eine eher theoretische Adjektiv - Bildung vom Verb "erreichen", dessen korrespondierende Substantiv "Erreichbarkeit" ist. Was Du suchst gibt es nicht.

Comment: @blk: Bitte editiere deine Frage, um diese Information einzubauen. Beachte aber bitte, dass "erreichend" streng genommen eher bedeutet, dass der Weg tatsächlich zurückgelegt wird, und nicht, dass er nur prinzipiell zurückgelegt werden kann. Dies kann etwaige Antwortende in die Irre führen.

Comment: Was ich suche gibt es aber als theoretisches Konzept und ist etwas anderes als *erreichbar sein*. "Was du suchst gibt es nicht." hilft mir daher leider überhaupt nicht weiter.

Comment: Klingt, als solltest Du Deinen Text umformulieren ;-)

Comment: Meine Frage oben? Oder welchen Text meinst du?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man kann im Deutschen grundsätzlich für fast alles ein Substantiv bilden.
Dies auf die Spitze zu treiben ist eins der Charakteristika des Amtsdeutschen.

Für das Anforderungsprofil des Fragestellers käme nach meinem Amtsdeutsch-Sprachgefühl zumindest im ersten Fall (*A erreicht (aktiv) B*) das laut DWDS existierende Substantiv "Erreichung" als Kandidat infrage. Im zweiten Fall (*A kann einen Weg hin zu B zurücklegen*) wäre wohl eine Neubildung "Erreichungsfähigkeit" erforderlich.

Answer (score 0):

Das Adjektiv "erreichbar" leitet sich vom Verb "erreichen" ab.

"erreichend" ist das Partizip Präsens von "erreichen" und kann in diesem konkreten Fall eher theoretisch auch adjektivisch genutzt werden.

Jetzt kann man auf zweierlei Arten argumentieren:

a) "erreichbar" und "erreichend" stehen etwa auf der gleichen Stufe, weil sie beide Adjektive sind oder sein können (wenn auch nicht bedeutungsgleich!), die von "erreichen abgeleitet sind. Das dazugehörige Substantiv ist also in jedem Fall "Erreichbarkeit". Demzufolge die Grundannahme nicht, dass es ein anderes Substantiv geben müsse, weil beide Adjektive sich vom gleichen Verb ableiten, einmal als eigenständige Form mit der Endung -bar und einmal als Partizip I, was in diesem Fall eine mindestens unübliche Form für ein adjektiven Gebrauch ist. Möglich wäre auch das inzwischen eher unübliche "Erreichung" (danke @Tilman Schmidt).

b) Du siehst das Adjektiv "erreichbar" und das Verb "erreichen" als die zu substantivierenden Worte an. Dann sind die korrespondierenden Worte "Erreichbarkeit" und "(das) Erreichen".

In diesem Fall würde ich deutlich Option (b), d.h. die Substantivierung des Verbs selbst bevorzugen.

Es gibt keine allgemeine Regel, welche Adjektive und korrespondierenden Substantive es für ein Verb und "dazugehörige" Adjektive und Substantive gibt. Auch muss es für einen gewissen Zustand nicht unbedingt ein Wort geben, welches diesen umfänglich beschreibt.

Ein weiteres Beispiel, was als Kontrast zeigen, wo diese Analogie klappt, sei hier "wässern": Davon kann ich Bedeutungs-verschiedene Adjektive ableiten: Möglich ist sowohl "wässrig", "wässerbar" als auch "wässernd". Hierzu kann ich aber mit jeweils anderen Endungen Substantive bilden: Wässrigkeit (auch wenn dieses vielleicht etwas schräg ist), Wässerbarkeit und Wässerung. Siehe auch den Kommentar von @HalvaF für ein weiteres Beispiel.

Comment: Der Satz "Der in Köln erreichbare Anschlusszug nach Bonn ist pünktlich." behauptet *die Erreichbarkeit* des Anschlusszuges in Köln. Der Satz "Der Bonn erreichende Zug ist pünktlich." impliziert *das Erreichen* Bonns durch den Zug. Ich bin ganz klar für (b). :-)
Manche andere Verben kennen noch ein Substantiv auf -ung, zum Beispiel berechnen - berechenbar - Berechnung - Berechenbarkeit.  Aber "Erreichung" gibt es nicht.

Comment: Dem [letzten Kommentar des OP](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/70258/erreichbar-zu-erreichbarkeit-wie-erreichend-zu#comment168049_70258) nach zu urteilen, geht es weniger darum, dass etwas tastächlich erreicht wird, und mehr darum, dass etwas die theoretische Möglichkeit hat, etwas anderes zu erreichen.

Comment: Letzteres ist richtig. Dementsprechend finde ich auch *Wässerung* in diesem Kontext nicht richtig. Es geht mir um ein Nomen zu *wässernd*: Einen Zustand, der beschreibt, dass A die Möglichkeit hat, B zu wässern.

Comment: PS: Das *erreichbar*-Pendant wäre tatsächlich, dass B wässerbar ist.

Comment: "Aber "Erreichung" gibt es nicht." - Anderer Ansicht: https://www.dwds.de/wb/Erreichung

Comment: Man lernt nie aus, ein grausiges Wort!

Answer (score 0):

Es gibt genau zwei Substantive, die vom Verb *»erreichen«* abgeleitet sind:

### Erreichbarkeit

Dieses Substantiv beschreibt eine **Möglichkeit**, dass etwas am Ende eines Vorgangs steht.

1. Das was erreicht werden soll (z.B. ein Berggipfel) existierte bereits vorher, lag damals aber in der Ferne. Jetzt befindet man sich genau am selben Ort.
2. Das was erreicht werden soll (z.B. die Fussion zweier Unternehmen) existierte vorher nicht, sonder wurde erst durch den Vorgang erschaffen.

### Erreichung

Dieses Substantiv beschreibt den sehr kurzen **Vorgang,** in dem die zuvor beschriebene Möglichkeit zur Realität wird.

---

Beide Substantive drehen sich also um das Ziel eines Vorgangs. Einmal als noch nicht realisierte Möglichkeit, das andere mal als Vorgang der Realisierung.

#### Andere Substantive, die vom Verb *erreichen* abgeleitet sind, gibt es nicht.

Comment: Das stimmt so nicht, denn wie jedes Verb lässt sich *erreichen* substantivieren. Demnach gibt es noch das Substantiv *Erreichen*.

Comment: Es stimmt nicht und ist ganz offensichtlich nicht hilfreich. Falls es (noch) kein Wort gibt, suche ich offenbar eine sinnvolle Wortneuschöpfung.